# Coq doesn't recognize equality of dependent list

Tags: coq, proof, dependent-type, proof-of-correctness, church-encoding

I made a question before, but i think that question was bad formalized so...
I am facing some problems with this specific definition to prove their properties:

I have a definition of a list :

```
Inductive list (A : Type) (f : A -> A -> A) : A -> Type :=
  |Acons : forall {x : A} (y' : A) (cons' : list f x), list f (f x y')
  |Anil : forall (x: A) (y : A), list f (f x y).
```

And that's definitions :

```
Definition t_list (T : Type) := (T -> T -> T) -> T -> T.
Definition nil {A : Type} (f : A -> A -> A) (d : A) := d.
Definition cons {A : Type} (v' : A) (c_cons : t_list _) (f : A -> A -> A) (v'' : A) :=
  f (c_cons f v'') v'.

Fixpoint list_correspodence (A : Type) (v' : A) (z : A -> A -> A) (xs : list func v'):=
  let fix curry_list {y : A} {z' : A -> A -> A} (l : list z' y) := 
      match l with
        |Acons x y => cons x (curry_list y)
        |Anil _ _ y  => cons y nil
      end in (@curry_list _ _ xs) z (let fix minimal_case {y' : A} {functor : A -> A -> A} (a : list functor y') {struct a} :=
                                    match a with
                                      |Acons x y => minimal_case y
                                      |Anil _ x _ => x
                                    end in minimal_case xs).

Theorem z_next_list_coorresp : forall {A} (z : A -> A -> A) (x y' : A) (x' : list z x), z (list_correspodence x') y' = list_correspodence (Acons y' x').
intros.
generalize (Acons y' x').
intros.
unfold list_correspodence.
(*reflexivity should works ?*)
Qed.
```

z_next_list_coorres is actually a lemma i need to prove a goal in another theory (v'_list x = (list_correspodence x)).

I have been trying with some limited scopes to prove list_correspodence and works well, seems that definitions are equal, but for coq not.

Comment: For some reason reusing the variable `A` as both a type and a list made this program incredibly hard for me to follow. It would also help readability to lift `curry_list` and `minimal_case` as toplevel `Fixpoint` instead of making them local functions like here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `list_correspondence` is a spurious `Fixpoint` (i.e., `fix`) (it makes no recursive calls), and this gets in the way of reduction.

You can force reduction of a `fix` by destructing its decreasing argument:

```
destruct x'.
- reflexivity.
- reflexivity.
```

Or you can avoid using `Fixpoint` in the first place. Use `Definition` instead.

You may run into a strange bug here with implicit arguments, which is avoided by adding a type signature (as below), or by not marking implicit the arguments of the local function `curry_list`:

```
Definition list_correspodence (A : Type) (v' : A) (func : A -> A -> A) (xs : list func v')
  : A :=
 (* ^ add this *)
```

Comment: It's not the first time i have problems with a leak of type signature i think i should don't use type inference anymore. And the Fixpoint i simply forgot take off this. Thank u so much. I appreciate your dedication.